# Why do the middle rows of my hollow right triangle all have the same size?

Tags: python

I have a task to create a hollow right triangle using a function. The question I have is how to print in numerical order.

So, starting with one in row one and ending in the last row with four characters. The code I have right now created the first and last rows. For the middle row I need it to have it in order but missing the middle if its greater than 2. I have a function that works and does this (`hollow_row`) but right now my code is just printing the given number without going from smallest to largest.

How can I fix this?

```
def triangle(char,n):
    middle_row = hollow_row(char,n)
    print(char*1)
    for i in range (n-2):
         print(middle_row)
    print(char*n)
```

What it prints:

```
#
#  #
#  #
####
```

What it needs to print:

```
#
##
# #
####
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are creating *one* `middle_row` which has the size of the base of the triangle (`n`) and which is used multiple times.

Instead, you need to create a *different* `middle_row` for each row, which has the size of that row (`i`).

After defining the value of a variable by calling a function, the function is not called again automatically each time the variable is used.

You need to call `hollow_row` in every iteration of the loop, not only once before the loop.

Comment: how would i change the size to i ? ive tried using len but that dosent work

Comment: Inside the loop, use `hollow_row(char, i)`. (Additionally, I think you need to adjust the start and stop values for `range`.)